# SQL to select current month MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm wondering if it it possible to SELECT records in which [RRRmonth] field is the current month? I've written this SQL in many ways and can't seen to get it to work.

```
SELECT CFRRR.CFRRRID, CFRRR.[program], CFRRR.[language]
FROM CFRRR
WHERE (((CFRRR.[workername]) Is Null) AND ((CFRRR.RRRmonth)=Month([RRRmonth])));
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of field is RRRmonth?

Comment: Hi @Robbert it's in Date/Time

Comment: Try this instead:  AND (((Month([CFRRR.RRRmonth]))=Month(Date())));  (But clean up the extra ")" I have.

Answer (score 1):

The month function will give you the month of a date/time field.  The date function will give you the current date.  Use the two together will give you the answer you're looking for

```
SELECT CFRRR.CFRRRID, CFRRR.[program], CFRRR.[language]
FROM CFRRR
WHERE CFRRR.[workername] Is Null AND month(CFRRR.[RRRmonth])=month(Date());
```

You also don't need all those parenthesis and makes for a messy query.